# Calculating a triple integral with polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Let
>   $$
> \Omega
> := \left\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: z>0, \ x^2+y^2<1, \ x>y^2+z^2-4 \right\}.
> $$
>   Find $\iiint_{\Omega}z\,dx\,dy\,dz$.

I'd like to know if my solution is correct
Using polar coordinates,
\begin{align}
\iiint_{\Omega}z \, dx\,dy\,dz
& = \int_{x^2+y^2<1}dx\,dy\int_0^{\sqrt{x-y^2+4}} z \ dz \\
&= \int_{x^2+y^2<1} \frac{x-y^2+4}{2} \ dx \ dy \\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 r \ dr\int_0^{2\pi}(r\cos(\theta)-r^2\sin^2(\theta)+4) \ d\theta
\end{align}
hence
$$
\iiint_{\Omega} z \ dx \ dy \ dz
= \int_0^1(4\pi r-\pi r^3/2)\ dr
= \frac{15}{8}\pi.
$$

Comment: But how do you get from $\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} r dr \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \ldots$ to $\int_{0}^{1} 4 \pi r dr$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to WolframAlpha,
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 r \ dr\int_0^{2\pi}(r\cos(\theta)-r^2\sin^2(\theta)+4) \ d\theta
= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 r \left(- \pi(r^2 - 8) \right) dr 
= \frac{15\pi}{8}.
$$